# Wrong page in toc using book document class

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, books

I am using this template for my book but am unable to correct page numbering for chapters. In TOC, it shows page 1 but actually, the chapter starts on page 2. I want chapter 1 to start on page 1.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fancybook-designeditorial/cxbxbgnghpfm

Comment: Please write a minimal working example (in the post itself, not an external link). See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: But it has too many subfiles and I can't post all that's why I used the overleaf link.

Comment: Thats why we ask for a MWE. Leave all the unnecessary subfiles and what not out. Maybe you even figure out the mistake on your own this way.

Comment: @HadiMalik Pretty much all you need is the `\documentclass...` `\begin{document}` `\tableofcontents` `\chapter{First}` `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate `chapter10.1.sty`  in `\fancyBook\template\fancyBook\local\lib\`

Change the #36 line from  `spread upwards,`  to  `spread upwards*,` to prevent the  start of a new page.

[image: a]